# SQL Show fields that match WHERE statement otherwise show the others

Tags: sql, ms-access

These are the parameters I am working with and I can get the entries to show up that match the Item 'Dress Shirt' but I don't know how to show the others if they don't match the 'Dress Shirt'.  I have been trying to use AND/OR but can't get it to show up right.

"Show the LastName, FirstName, Phone and Total Amount of all customers who have had an order with an Item named "Dress Shirt".  Also show the LastName, FirstName and Phone of all other customers.  Present results sorted by LastName in ascending order and then FirstName in descending order."

```
SELECT LastName, FirstName, Phone, TotalAmount
FROM Customer, Invoice, Invoice_Item
WHERE Customer.CustomerID = Invoice.CustomerNumber AND Invoice.InvoiceNumber = 
Invoice_Item.InvoiceNumber AND Item ='Dress Shirt';
```

Comment: I am using MS Access

Comment: which table does `Item ='Dress Shirt'` come from?

Comment: Should be pulling from Invoice_Item

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
SELECT LastName, FirstName, Phone, TotalAmount
FROM Customer
INNER JOIN Invoice ON Customer.CustomerID = Invoice.CustomerNumber
LEFT JOIN Invoice_Item ON Invoice.InvoiceNumber = Invoice_Item.InvoiceNumber 
                      AND invoice_item.Item ='Dress Shirt'
;
```

Access might insist on parenthese for the joins, something like this:

```
SELECT LastName, FirstName, Phone, TotalAmount
FROM ((Customer
INNER JOIN Invoice ON Customer.CustomerID = Invoice.CustomerNumber)
LEFT JOIN Invoice_Item ON Invoice.InvoiceNumber = Invoice_Item.InvoiceNumber 
                      AND invoice_item.Item ='Dress Shirt')
;
```

If you aren't familiar with left joins then [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25954456/left-join-returns-same-result-as-inner-join/25965107#25965107) may help.

Comment: I get an error saying "JOIN expression not supported."

Comment: Although I haven't used Access for years and years this syntax Access does support; You have to enter this as a whole query, there is a way to do it but I can't tell you where. Or, there is an option I think in the query by grid when you add a table to implement a left join - but again I can't tell you exactly how

Comment: I do appreciate your guidance though. Thank you! I'll keep messing with it.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Lastname, FirstName, Phonem TotalAmount
FROM (Customer INNER JOIN Invoice ON Customer.CustomerID=Invoice.CustomerNumber) `LEFT JOIN Invoice_Item ON Invoice.InvoiceNumber=Invoice_item.InvoiceNumber
Where Invoice_item.Item='Dress Shirt'
Order by LastName, FirstName DESC;
```

Comment: Select lastname, firstname, phone, totalamount

Comment: Can you explain how this fixes it? Thanks!

Comment: In MS Access, you need to put parentheses between join on syntax.

Comment: Ah, is it just the one set of parentheses needed! darn